# Splitting a list of objects based on a property c#

Tags: c#

myClass structure :

```
public class myClass
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string AdditionalData { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime ActivityTime { get; set; }
    }
```

I have a list of the above class `List<myClass>` all ordered by ActivityTime.

I need to split the above list and get a `List<List<myClass>>` such that if there is a difference of more than a specific period say 5 mins between two consecutive ActivityTime  I wish the split to take place.

Any help is sincerely appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I'd start with making a method that takes two `myClass` instances and returns the number of minutes in between them. Then run through the list and use that method to determine on which instances the split should happen. Take small steps so you can ask for advice on a specific issue.

Comment: An alternative could be a linq-GroupBy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Various approaches this can be achieved, but underlying principle is same. Keep track of `n-1`(th) element when processing `n(th)` element and calculate `timespan`  between these two.

You could do something like this.

```
List<MyClass> data = ...; // input
int gid=0;
DateTime prevvalue = data[0].ActivityTime;                          // Initial value 

var result =  data.Select(x=>
{
    var obj =  x.ActivityTime.Subtract(prevvalue).TotalMinutes<5?  // Look for timespan difference
                 new {gid= gid, item =x}                          // Create groups based on consecutive gaps. 
                :new {gid= ++gid, item =x};
    prevvalue= x.ActivityTime;                                      // Keep track of previous value (for next element process)
    return obj;
})
.GroupBy(x=>x.gid)                                                  // Split into groups 
.Select(x=>x.Select(s=>s.item).ToList())
.ToList();
```

Check this [`Demo`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/NDp7pQ)

Comment: 2nd, third and forth value should be in same group

Comment: Ahh.. I got it, when less then 5 minutes I should keep in same group.

Answer (score 3):

What about this [solution](https://dotnetfiddle.net/2X5hRf):

```
var data = new List<myClass> {
    new myClass { ActivityTime = new DateTime(2016, 01, 01, 01, 00, 00) },
    new myClass { ActivityTime = new DateTime(2016, 01, 01, 01, 05, 00) },
    new myClass { ActivityTime = new DateTime(2016, 01, 01, 01, 06, 00) },
    new myClass { ActivityTime = new DateTime(2016, 01, 01, 01, 07, 00) },
    new myClass { ActivityTime = new DateTime(2016, 01, 01, 01, 17, 00) }
};

var period = 5;
var firstActivityTime = data.Min(x => x.ActivityTime);
var answer = data.OrderBy(x => x.ActivityTime).GroupBy(x => {
        var dif = (x.ActivityTime - firstActivityTime).Minutes;
        return dif / period - (dif % period == 0 && dif / period != 0 ? 1 : 0);
    }).Select(x => x.ToList()).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks but the break has to happen if the difference between two consecutive Activity-time is more than 5 mins, in your example there should be only one break .. the last one being in the second group

Answer (score 3):

You can do that in a simple iteration:

```
var myList = new List<myClass>()
{
    new myClass() { Name = "ABC", AdditionalData = "1", ActivityTime = DateTime.Now },
    new myClass() { Name = "ABC2", AdditionalData = "2", ActivityTime = DateTime.Now },
    new myClass() { Name = "ABC3", AdditionalData = "3", ActivityTime = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(6) },
    new myClass() { Name = "ABC4", AdditionalData = "3", ActivityTime = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(11) },
    new myClass() { Name = "ABC4", AdditionalData = "3", ActivityTime = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(12) }
};

var results = new List<List<myClass>>();

myClass previousItem = null;
List<myClass> currentList = new List<myClass>();
foreach (var item in myList)
{
    if (previousItem == null || (item.ActivityTime - previousItem.ActivityTime).TotalSeconds >= 5)
    {
        currentList = new List<myClass>();
        results.Add(currentList);
    }

    currentList.Add(item);
    previousItem = item;
}
```

Comment: your code is working but just trying to understand ..if previousitem is null, why is currentlist again initialised and added to results. also if  diff in time condition is present then you first initialise a new currentlist and add it to results..  so why does results not get an empty currentlist

Comment: @Arnab `previousitem` is `null` only in the first iteration. We create a new list every time the difference is more than 5 seconds. This is exactly your requirement. `currentList` can't be empty because every iteration we add an item to it.

Comment: The code is working perfectly, just trying to understand it, when you do - currentList = new List<myClass>();
        results.Add(currentList);
why does not an empty currentlist get initialised and get added to results

Comment: On every iteration u r adding to currentlist.. so currentlist is normally not empty.. so if we do .. "List<int> list = new List<int>();
  list.Add(2);
  list.Add(3);
  list.Add(5);
  list.Add(7); " We have a list which has values. Now if I do" list =  new List<int>();" all old values in list goes off and I have an empty list.. why does something similar not happen in your case..

Comment: @Arnab `currentList = new List<myClass>();` points `currentList` variable to a newly create list. **It doesn't clear the previous list** whose reference is still at some index of `results`. You need to read more about the differene between `Reference types` and `value types`. I advise you to google that.

Comment: you are spot on.. my knowledge of basics in coding is horrible to say the least.. but still normally, when I get a code, I do understand, but this time I'm completely flummoxed..

Comment: @Arnab Don't worry. We all started the same.